# End of month with nan's in date

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have Series, type datetime, some values is NaT

Trying to get end of month and save NaT if the date is NaT.

My variant:
`conditions = [pd.notnull(df['date'])]

choices= [df['date'].dt.date + relativedelta(day=31)]

df['en_of_month'] = np.select(conditions, choices, df['date'])`

But I get error: IllegalMonthError: bad month number nan; must be 1-12

Expected result

| date | month |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-31 |
| NaT | NaT |
| 2023-04-10 | 2023-04-30 |

Comment: `df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)`